# How can I detect the device from which my website is accessed?

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have .NET website that is mainly built for desktop browsers but I'm currently making a mobile version of it. What I'm trying to do is load the website according to the device on which it is accessed by the user. Is there a way that I can get information about the user's device when they request the site?

Regards,
Sumit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by others you can use the `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities` class accessible through `Request.Browser` however without updated [browser definition files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx) the information is completely worthless.

For example, if you use `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` this *should* give you what you want, but is based on a set of very dated regular expressions in your .NET framework folders in Windows.

You can see the kind of problems that can be encountered on a (currently unanswered and unloved) post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166763/why-am-i-getting-these-strange-results-when-looking-at-browser-capabilities) on Stack Overflow.

**If you do not plan on keeping the browser definition files up to date (which is no small task) then quite simply do not go down this route**.

If you simply want to know whether the user is viewing on a mobile device then here are a few options:

- [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)
- [51Degrees.mobi](https://51degrees.mobi/)
- [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
- [User Agent Info](http://user-agent-string.info/)

Some of those are free, some aren't and if you are really only interested in whether it is a mobile device, my recommendation would be to use Detect Mobile Browsers.

Comment: +1 nice answer.  The built in stuff just doesn't keep up with the many devices that are out there these days.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`HttpBrowserCapabilities`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx) class.

> Enables the server to gather information on the capabilities of the browser that is running on the client.

This is actually exposed on the `Request` property of the `Page` object - in an ASP.NET page you can do the following:

```
var browserCap = this.Request.Browser;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the HttpRequest.Browser property - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something more low level: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A commercial alernative is [BrowserHawk](http://cyscape.com)