# ASP.NET - How to find out if the user is a mobile user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I am trying to find out if a user viewing my site is a mobile user. I have used "HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice " and found it pretty useless as it didn't not pick up on my usage when viewing the site on my phone.

Is there another way to find out if the user is a mobile user that works better?

I have looked at user agent and that just looks messy!

I should point out that this has nothing to do with CSS, I want to log if the user is a mobile user in a database table.

And yes, I know google analytics can do this already but unfortunately its not my decision!

Thanks

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446264/how-can-i-detect-the-device-from-which-my-website-is-accessed/8448800#8448800

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to test with this code....

```
    string sUA = Request.UserAgent.Trim().ToLower();

    uaString.InnerText = Request.UserAgent;

    if (sUA.Contains("ipod") || sUA.Contains("iphone"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (sUA.Contains("android"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (sUA.Contains("opera mobi"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (sUA.Contains("windows phone os") && sUA.Contains("iemobile"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (sUA.Contains("fennec"))
        isMobile = true;
```

Comment: Let's just hope nobody uses a Blackberry. Or a Palm device. Terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: This will not always work. I'd strongly recommend not using a brittle scheme like this. The 51degrees answer (or anything using a more comprehensive database) is a much more complex, yet reliable solution. I have gone down this road before and it was unusable. We got to the point where we had 60 if statements similar to the above and we were still hitting cases where the detection was incorrect.  I can tell you from experience you'll be happier if you go with a more complete solution.

Comment: It seems like a more robust approach may be to inspect the resolution of the device and categorize it that way.

Comment: what is uaString.InnerText ?

Answer (score 7):

Check out

[51degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/)

> It’s provided as a .NET open source class library that detects mobile
>   devices and browsers, enhancing the information available to .NET
>   programmers. Using 51Degrees.mobi Device Data, accurate screen sizes,
>   input methods, plus manufacturer and model information are all
>   available. Mobile handsets can optionally be redirected to content
>   designed for mobile devices. Smart phones, tablets and feature phones
>   are all supported.

As pointed out in the comments.

> The detection and redirection part of the product offering is free.
>   The free trial is for their mobile optimzation products

Comment: This is only a free trial - you have to pay $$ to use it.

Comment: +1.  I have used 51degrees with great success.  There is no easy way to look at a user agent string to determine a mobile browser but 51degrees pulls it off.  They do this by using a comprehensive database of mobile user agent strings.  A word of warning, update frequently.  If you don't you could either erroneously determine that a new browser (or update) is mobile when it isn't, or fail to detect that a browser is in fact mobile.  If you update frequently you won't have these problems.

Comment: IIRC, 51degrees uses WURFL as it's datasource.

Comment: @IrishChieftain the detection and redirection part of the product offering is free.  The free trial is for their mobile optimzation products.

Comment: @IrishChieftain The foundation product that does detection is right there on codeplex for download (including source.)  That is the very product that we use.  If you click the free trial link it takes you to 51degrees.mobi where they offer other products.

Comment: [WURFL itself seems to have a .NET API as well.](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotNet/) But the linked question already has all these in the answers.

Comment: I also think it is worth pointing out that 51degrees is an httpmodule and will update the HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice using the WURFL database rather than the built in asp.net detection.

Comment: @Devin I am playing around with this right now, problem is I have no idea how to tell if 51d is doing the work or the built in detection. Any idea how I can test to make sure it's still not using the default method?

Comment: @Ryan when I implemented this I just hit my test website with my smart phone both with and without the 51 degrees configuration.  I could see the difference in the reported browser capabilities pretty easily.  You could also debug the module since you get the source code and watch it set the new values.

Comment: @Devin thanks, yeah when I pulled the DLL out of /bin I could see the detection drop away, I just thought I could yank the .config entries but it turns out I don't even need those for .NET 4 to get the detection, if the DLL is in the /bin it works

Comment: As the CodePlex is shutting down, So the 51Degrees has been moved to
[Github](https://github.com/51Degrees/dotNET-Device-Detection)

Answer (score 6):

See my comment on your question for a more thorough answer, but for a simple check to see if the user is a mobile user I would personally suggest

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/